# Is it possible to run tests using the nUnit framework in a hosted website?

Tags: .net, asp.net, nunit

First, let me pledge my allegiance to unit testing over integration testing, I like unit testing very much.

But I have other tests that are essentially deployment tests (you can't test how the production deployment went using a unit test on a build server) and I'd like to use the nUnit framework to run these.

But, the production server doesn't have the nUnit command line executer.  I'm only allowed to run aspx pages and reference .dll's in bin.

What do I need to do to run tests (yeah, yeah, they're not really unit tests--relax) using nUnit in a webpage?  Is there a straight forward way to do this, or does this essentially require porting the nUnit winforms test runner to ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2):

> or does this essentially require
>   porting the nUnit winforms test runner
>   to ASP.NET?

Whoa don't do that! There are alternatives like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) that will allow you to do web page automation.

Use [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) to generate a broad test script, and then you can export that as an NUnit test to be run using [Selenium Remote Control](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/).

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into those.